# Virtualbox Hostonly Network Configuration on laptop runing windows 7 64-bit

Tags: networking, ubuntu, windows-7, virtualbox

I installed Virtualbox on my workplace laptop to run Lubuntu in Windows-7 64-bit. I have some issues to make the hostonly network work with wireless adapter.

The wireless adapter will turn off once wired adapter is connected.

When I disconnect the wired adapter, wireless network doesn't turn on. Current active network points to Virtualbox Hostonly adapter. Only after I disable the hostonly adapter, I can turn on wireless adapter.

How can I make the wireless adapter turn on without disable virtualbox hostonly adapter?

Comment: Not really programming related.

Answer (score 1):

VirtualBox doesn't correctly notify Windows 7 that the Host-Only Adapter is virtual.  As a result, it shows up as an unidentified public network.  It sounds like that may be the source of your problem.

To correct the issue, you must make a minor addition to the registry.  First you need to locate the key associated with the VirtualBox host adaptor:

1. Under **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}**, locate the key containing the string **DriverDesc** with a value of "**VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter**"
2. Within the key you located (something like '00XX'), add a **DWORD** value with the name "***NdisDeviceType**" and a value of "**1**".
3. Reboot.

Additional rationale for making this change and examples of PowerShell scripts that can automatically make it for you can be found [here](http://brianreiter.org/2010/09/18/fix-virtualbox-host-only-network-adapter-creates-a-virtual-public-network-connection-that-causes-windows-to-disable-services/) or [here](http://www.brokenwire.net/bw/Various/120/fix-virtualbox-causes-unidentified-network-on-vista-and-windows-7).  I have not tested either PowerShell script, so your mileage may vary.