# How to set network location for VirtualBox Host-Only Network adapter on Windows 8 between private/public?

Tags: windows-8, virtualbox, windows-server-2008

I have configured a Windows Server 2008 guest on VirtualBox v5.0.10 on a Windows 8 host laptop. They work fine and ping each other on bridged mode, IP address are served by a wireless router.

Whenever I take the laptop off the Wi-Fi network, this setup no longer works, so I have switched to a host-only config with DHCP server enabled.

By default, Windows places all networks as public, and I was unable to change it until I found [this article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f30cb69d-7c32-4ed7-8c9c-3b75db7a06fd/how-to-change-network-location-in-windows-server-2008-r2-or-windows-7-for-unidentified-network?forum=winserverPN) which says that you need to provide a default gateway entry for the NIC to be able to set the network location. After doing that (set gateway to host IP address), I could change the location and could ping the guest from the host.

I did the same on Windows 8 host. When I changed the gateway address to point to the guest IP address, I was prompted from the charms bar: *"Do you want to turn on sharing between PCs and connect to devices on this network?"*. I chose Yes. Now the guest can ping the host.

Problem is, now I can't access that same configuration again. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/change-network-location-windows-8/) but the "VirtualBox Host-Only Network" adapter won't show on the network list (I'm not running Windows 8 Pro, so I don't have "Local Group Policy Editor" gpedit.msc). I would expect something like this below, but I don't see the "Connections" section, only Wi-Fi:

[image: Screen shot of the Networks charm bar with the lists connections and wi-fi][1]

From reading [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/436617/virtualbox-hostonly-network-configuration-on-laptop-runing-windows-7-64-bit#471346) to a different question, my guess is that because the network card on the host side is virtual, it's hidden from the charms bar network configuration.

So how can I alternate the "Network location" between Public/Private for the "VirtualBox Host-Only Network" adapter on Windows 8? Is there a way to make it visible on the "Connections" list?